# When guide someone to think something which one is more appropriate, "find" or "find out"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions, idiomatic-language

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845964/10443608) just now, but I am not sure I expressed appropriately.

I am trying to guide the guy who posted this question to look into source code

> take a look at the source code, you'll find out that TruncatedSVD is
>   based on `randomized_svd`

In this case, which one is more appropriate, "find" or "find out"?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "Find out" is grammatically correct, as the definition matches the point that you are trying to get across.
(Definition of find out:  to learn by study, observation, or search)
(Definition of find: discover or perceive by chance or unexpectedly.)